# Better design of database for Hospital Bed charges between two approaches

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a database for a hospital bed charges. I am little bit confused as to which approach is better.

Which way It will be easier to maintain and query the database?

Personally I feel that first approach is better.

**approach1**

```
room_no charges_cash    charges_cashless
MG1      300                400
MG2      400                500
```

**approach2**

```
room_no charges  cash_cashless
MG1      300     cash
MG1      400     cashless
MG2      400     cash
MG2      500     cashless
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would personally recommend approach 1, because it requires less lines and makes it easier to perform Joins on room_no

Comment: That depends on your data model. Is cash and cashless always a required data point which always must be attached to a single row? Then making that a column is a logical thing to do. Otherwise, if the room_no has a more dynamic relationship to those charges, it may make sense to do it the other way.

Comment: Urgh. Someone _charges_ for a hospital appointment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, I would use option two.

From a relational database design point of view, I agree with Flosculus as if you wanted to add additional types of charges in the future (e.g. split cashless into credit-card, Paypal, Worldpay etc), then in option one you would need to alter the schema, but in option two you don't; just use different value in cash_cashless (and maybe rename that column to "payment_type" or something?)

For example:

**Rooms Table**

```
Room_No  Room_Name   Other_Columns
MG1      Room One          *
MG2      Room Two          *
```

**Charges Table**

```
Charge_ID Room_no Charge  Payment_Type
1         MG1      300     cash
2         MG1      400     cashless
3         MG2      400     cash
4         MG2      500     cashless  
5         MG2      450     cheque
6         MG2      600     creditcard
```

Also, from a performance point of view you may well find option two it scales better over time, as you can be more fine-grained in your queries and it allows you to create more efficient indexes.

If you wanted to make only one type of charge available for each room, they you could use a compound primary key from the [Room_no] and [Payment_Type] columns.

Answer (score 1):

The first one. In that way, you can use your `room_no` as a primary key. Second one is good, when it's not a master data, when it's a relation table. This based on your database design.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you would use approach 2 is if you are designing the database to scale with requirements.

The first one will be easier to query, but the second will allow you to add additional values to the cash_cashless column, although you would rename it to something more generic to handle different types.

In this case your requirements may be limited to these 2 cash and cashless, but the second approach is generally used for the above reason.

Answer (score 0):

I will go with the price in one field and cash in another, to avoid the data duplication of other field in case you create two rows for one payment